# createTriangleMesh unhandled exception

Tags: c++, opengl, physx

I am using PhysX, OpenGL and assimp. I am getting 'unhandled exception ..... Access violation reading location 0x00000' at the last line

```
void CreateActor(const aiScene *scene)
{
NxTriangleMeshDesc t;
aiMesh *mesh = scene->mMeshes[0];
t.numVertices = mesh->mNumVertices;
t.points = mesh->mVertices;
t.pointStrideBytes = sizeof(aiVector3D);
t.numTriangles = mesh->mNumFaces;
NxU32 *tr = new NxU32[mesh->mNumFaces*3];
NxU32 k=0;
for(NxU32 i=0;i<mesh->mNumFaces;i++)
    for(int j=0;j<3;j++)
        tr[k++]=mesh->mFaces[i].mIndices[j];
t.triangles = tr;
t.triangleStrideBytes = sizeof(NxU32)*3;
t.flags=0;
NxTriangleMeshShapeDesc terrainShapeDesc; 

 // Cooking from memory
 InitCooking();
 MemoryWriteBuffer buf;
 bool status = CookTriangleMesh(t, buf);
 MemoryReadBuffer readBuffer(buf.data);
 gPhysicsSDK->createTriangleMesh(readBuffer);
}
```

Using Assimp::Importer I have read a simple cube in .x
It has 24 vertices, 12 faces.
point of using 2 for loops with 'mesh->mFaces[i].mIndices[j]' is that there is a mNumIndices algong with mIndices

I know the function CreateActor is incomplete, but the error was on the 'createTriangleMesh' (last line) so I omitted rest.

Comment: When is `gPhysicsSDK` initialized?  My first guess would be that's the null pointer.

Comment: LOL, you are right. Can't believe it. Actually before I was equating the triangles directly with assimp-mesh->faces (without the for loops) and it was failing to cook. So I copied some code from samples, and I think that skipped the InitNx() 'Oh GOD'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gPhysicsSDK was NULL, so that was the whole problem.
For anyone who uses PhysX and wish to load various 3D models (.3DS, .X, .obj, etc) you can find the above code handy (except you'll have to loop through all aimesh), google assimp.

Thanks Tyler